# Get failed requirement or policy in AuthorizeRouteView.NotAuthorized

Tags: asp.net, authentication, authorization, blazor

I use the `<AuthorizeRouteView>` component in a Blazor WASM application to check the user's authorization with respect to the current page. The page has appropriate `[Authorize]` attributes applied to it.

The `<NotAuthorized>` attribute of the view allows to add components for the case when the user is not authorized to access the page. Is there a way to find the reason why the user is not authorized (i.e., more or less get the content of the page's `[Authorize]` attribute)? This is especially important if the user can do something about the failed authorization requirement. E.g., when a specific page requires multi-factor authentication, I would like to prompt the user to provide an additional factor rather than just telling him that he is not authorized to view this page.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  Having exactly the same problem/requirement.

Comment: @Paul: Unfortunately not. I ended up encapsulating the page content in a separate component that displays its content only if strong authentication methods are used. Otherwise, the component asks the user for additional authentication. But I need to know the requirements of the page beforehand. Not an option for dynamic scenarios.

Comment: Ok thanks. I didn't work it out either, but I did come up with a fairly lightweight workaround/alternative. Just a simple class that stores the failure reason that has a scoped lifetime. I can inject the reason wherever I need. Feels like a hack though.

Comment: You could maybe extract all requirements from failed policy and test them one by one